# Start spark standalone master with Upstart

Tags: apache-spark, upstart

I'm an Upstart newbie (and a Spark newbie for that matter),

I've been able to start a spark standalone server using:

```
./spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4/sbin/start-master.sh
```

and I want this to start automatically every time the computer is turned on, I looked up Upstart and wrote this simple conf file:

```
 description "satrt a spark master with Upstart"
 author "Ezer"
 exec bash -c '/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4/sbin/start-master start'
```

it does not work and I get the filling I'm missing something basic, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some error log to show?

Comment: Why do you give 'start' as parameter and when running it by command line you don't?

Comment: I got this off someplace explaining how to run a script in upstart, I'll check without it and let you know

Comment: exec bash -c '/spark-1.5.2-bin-hadoop2.4/sbin/start-master'  does not work

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
export SPARK_HOME={YOUR_ACTUAL_SPARK_HOME_PATH}
exec bash $SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-all.sh
```

in your upstart `conf` file? However, note the script spawn processes so you cannot actually manage the service with `upstart`.